# setState() does not update Image widget after data is passed back from another screen

Tags: flutter

I currently have a screen where if you type into a search field it navigates you to a 2nd screen **(ImageResults())** that displays images based upon the search keyword. When you select an image on the 2nd screen, the image url is passed back to the 1st screen and the image should be displayed as a preview.

I did a print statement **print(image)** to check if the 2nd screen successfully passed the url to the 1st screen and it did. However, the image widget is not updating even after calling setState() and keeps displaying the image when **image == null** is true when the print statement indicates that image is not null and contains the selected image url.

Any thoughts on what's going on? Thanks!

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String? image;
    TextEditingController _searchInputController = TextEditingController();
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(
              controller: _searchInputController,
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.search,
              onSubmitted: (String keyword) async {
                var data = await getPics(_searchInputController.text);
                final _image = await Navigator.of(context).push(createRoute(
                    ImageResults(_searchInputController.text, data['photos'])));
                setState(() {
                  _searchInputController.text = '';
                  image = _image;
                });
                print(image);
              },
            ),
            image == null
                ? ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    child: Image.asset(
                      'assets/activity.jpg',
                      height: 200,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .6,
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  )
                : ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    child: Image.network(
                      image!,
                      height: 200,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .6,
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move your variable declarations outside the build function. Because if your image variable is inside the build function, it will be set to null after your setState()

```dart
String? image;

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  //...
}
```

I'd recommend you do that for your `TextEditingController` as well

Comment: Thanks Roaa, that was indeed the issue

Comment: You're welcome!